# OutOfMemoryException while making a Http GET request

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-3.1

Its a straight forward scenario: make the request and convert the json result into equivalent POCO class.
Initially I was converting the response to string and then deserializing it :

```
    private async Task<T> CallApiAsync<T>(string url)
        {
            var httpResponseMessage = await _httpClient.GetAsync(url);
            if (httpResponseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var responseBody = await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync(); // this one here
                return Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(responseBody);
            }
            var errors = await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            throw DomainError(httpResponseMessage.StatusCode, url, errors);
        }
```

For which I used to get this intermittent error:

```
"Message": "Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.",
  "Source": "System.Private.CoreLib",
  "StackTraceString": "   at System.String.CreateStringFromEncoding(Byte* bytes, Int32 byteLength, Encoding encoding)
  in /_/src/System.Private.CoreLib/shared/System/String.cs:line 505\n 
  at System.Text.UTF8Encoding.GetString(Byte[] bytes, Int32 index, Int32 count)
  in /_/src/System.Private.CoreLib/shared/System/Text/UTF8Encoding.cs:line 663\n   
  at System.Net.Http.HttpContent.ReadBufferAsString(ArraySegment`1 buffer, HttpContentHeaders headers) 
  in /_/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/HttpContent.cs:line 223\n  
  at System.Net.Http.HttpContent.ReadBufferedContentAsString() in /_/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/HttpContent.cs:line 182\n 
  at System.Net.Http.HttpContent.WaitAndReturnAsync[TState,TResult](Task waitTask, TState state, Func`2 returnFunc)
  in /_/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/HttpContent.cs:line 717\n 
  at Infrastructure.Clients.SecurityMasterFileService.CallApiAsync[T](String url)
  in /app/Infrastructure/Clients/SecurityMasterFileService.cs:line 68\n
```

So I **switched to** **reading from stream** since there was no point converting to string and hogging up the memory:

```
private async Task<T> CallApiAsync<T>(string url)
        {
            using var httpResponseMessage = await _httpClient.GetAsync(url); //added "using"
            if (httpResponseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                using var responseBody = await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync(); //changed this line 
                return await System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.DeserializeAsync<T>(responseBody); //also changed from Newtonsoft to System.Text since the former did not have async overload
            }
            var errors = await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            throw DomainError(httpResponseMessage.StatusCode, url, errors);
        }
```

Now I am getting this intermittent error:

```
"Message": "Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown.",
  "Source": "System.Private.CoreLib",
  "StackTraceString": "   at System.IO.MemoryStream..ctor(Int32 capacity)
  in /_/src/System.Private.CoreLib/shared/System/IO/MemoryStream.cs:line 47\n 
  at System.Net.Http.HttpContent.CreateMemoryStream(Int64 maxBufferSize, Exception& error)
  in /_/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/HttpContent.cs:line 522\n  
  at System.Net.Http.HttpContent.LoadIntoBufferAsync(Int64 maxBufferSize, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
  in /_/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/HttpContent.cs:line 430\n 
  at System.Net.Http.HttpClient.FinishSendAsyncBuffered(Task`1 sendTask, HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationTokenSource cts, Boolean disposeCts) 
  in /_/src/System.Net.Http/src/System/Net/Http/HttpClient.cs:line 546\n 
  at Infrastructure.Clients.SecurityMasterFileService.CallApiAsync[T](String url) in /app/Infrastructure/Clients/SecurityMasterFileService.cs:line 68\n
```

So now I am wondering what further needs to be fixed in the new implementation. Can someone point me out in the correct direction. Thank you.

*Edit*: Adding the json payload : https://jsonblob.com/4d2eac0f-f42a-11eb-9b1d-736dff69cd5c

Note: From the json payload I require only the first 2 objects, so I have a POCO class for the first two:

```
    public class Root
    {
        public RootA RootA { get; set; }
        public RootB RootB { get; set; }
    }
    public class RootA
    {
        public string Field1 { get; set; }
        public string Field2 { get; set; }
        public int Field3 { get; set; }
        public string Field4 { get; set; }
        public string Field5 { get; set; }
        public int Field6 { get; set; }
        public int Field7 { get; set; }
        public string Field8 { get; set; }
        public string Field9 { get; set; }
        public int Field10 { get; set; }
        public int Field11 { get; set; }
        public int Field12 { get; set; }
        public int Field13 { get; set; }
        public DateTime Field14 { get; set; }
        public string Field15 { get; set; }
        public DateTime Field16 { get; set; }
        public string Field17 { get; set; }
        public string Field18 { get; set; }
        public string Field19 { get; set; }
        public string Field20 { get; set; }
        public string Field21 { get; set; }
        public string Field22 { get; set; }
        public string Field23 { get; set; }
        public string Field24 { get; set; }
        public string Field25 { get; set; }
        public string Field26 { get; set; }
        public DateTime Field27 { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootB
    {
        public string Field1 { get; set; }
        public string Field2 { get; set; }
        public DateTime Field3 { get; set; }
        public string Field4 { get; set; }
        public string Field5 { get; set; }
        public string Field6 { get; set; }
        public string Field7 { get; set; }
        public string Field8 { get; set; }
        public int Field9 { get; set; }
        public int Field10 { get; set; }
        public int Field11 { get; set; }
        public int Field12 { get; set; }
        public int Field13 { get; set; }
        public string Field14 { get; set; }
        public int Field15 { get; set; }
        public int Field16 { get; set; }
        public int Field17 { get; set; }
        public int Field18 { get; set; }
        public int Field19 { get; set; }
        public int Field20 { get; set; }
        public int Field21 { get; set; }
        public string Field22 { get; set; }
        public int Field23 { get; set; }
        public string Field24 { get; set; }
        public int Field25 { get; set; }
        public int Field26 { get; set; }
        public string Field27 { get; set; }
        public int Field28 { get; set; }
        public int Field29 { get; set; }
        public string Field30 { get; set; }
        public int Field31 { get; set; }
        public string Field32 { get; set; }
        public string Field33 { get; set; }
        public string Field34 { get; set; }
        public string Field35 { get; set; }
        public string Field36 { get; set; }
        public string Field37 { get; set; }
        public int Field38 { get; set; }
        public string Field39 { get; set; }
        public int Field40 { get; set; }
        public string Field41 { get; set; }
        public DateTime Field42 { get; set; }
        public DateTime Field43 { get; set; }
        public DateTime Field44 { get; set; }
        public string Field45 { get; set; }
        public DateTime Field46 { get; set; }
        public DateTime Field47 { get; set; }
        public string Field48 { get; set; }
        public int Field49 { get; set; }
        public string Field50 { get; set; }
        public string Field51 { get; set; }
        public DateTime Field52 { get; set; }
        public string Field53 { get; set; }
        public string Field54 { get; set; }
        public string Field55 { get; set; }
        public int Field56 { get; set; }
        public string Field57 { get; set; }
        public string Field58 { get; set; }
        public string Field59 { get; set; }
        public string Field60 { get; set; }
        public string Field61 { get; set; }
        public DateTime Field62 { get; set; }
        public string Field63 { get; set; }
        public int Field64 { get; set; }
        public string Field65 { get; set; }
        public string Field66 { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: A copy of the JSON message that is received would be nice. If you cannot give that (because of privacy, or so), the size of that message would be the least info. Can you share that?

Comment: and id you try to save the response, and check if the JSON is valid?

Comment: How freaking huge is the response you're getting? For obvious reasons, `HttpClient` isn't optimised for massive amounts of data.

Comment: Let me rename the json fields and share it

Comment: How big is the payload? Be precise.

Comment: @Luuk : added json payload.

Comment: @IanKemp I dont have control over the json payload, it is owned by some one else. So if not ```HttpClient``` then what are the alternatives

Comment: The JSON is not really huge - there must be going something wrong. Can you please check if you are calling your code in an endless loop via debugger?

Comment: Are you running your application in 32 bit mode or 64 bit? In 32 bit mode you can end up in Large Object Heap fragmentation issues and in this case end up with OutOfMemory Exception.

Comment: @Compufreak
I am calling the api in a for loop, catching if any exception is occuring and finally terminating:
(`foreach (var item in list){try{// call Api with ids } catch (Exception e) {//log the exception;continue; }`)

Comment: How many items are in list? Are you storing your results? Do some calls succeed before the exception occurs?

Comment: @Compufreak I dont have control over that either, on dev environment I comes to be like 167000. So basically the list contains string of ids, and correspoinding to each id I get a json result,  and instead of calling 1 by 1 I call them in a batch size  say 500

Comment: @Compufreak As and when I get the response I store them in a database (inside the try block of the loop. Do some calls succeed before the exception, I think yes. It fails somewhere in between. I compared the count of the list and database count which was where the mismatch was, and checking the logs showed the memory exception

Comment: @KoryakovKonstantsin I have to check that. I'll get back on this

Comment: @IanKemp added json payload

Comment: @afrose, how many `Root`, `RootA` and `RootB` payloads are you requesting 1, 5, 1000?

Comment: @DekuDesu that would depend on the initial list size, which varies from one env to another. Say about 0.2 million and above

Comment: @afrose, you may want to open a stream to the incoming json, and pipe the data to a separate thread to be de-serialized, JSON has a stream deserializer. Another option is to stream the incoming json directly to a file handle and de-serialize is later / concurrently. I would recommend avoiding having any sitting data while operations are completing, AKA dont store any thing in properties, fields or variables, and *purely* pipe it around until the final object/storage location

Comment: I'd also try to look at other parts of your loop - it might not be the JSON parsing itself causing the memory to fill up, it's just the part where the memory is finally full and the issue manifests itself in an exception. It might be that you are using Entity Framework and cache the objects supposed to be commited to the database, initialise objects that are not garbage collected inside the loop, etc. As the JSON deserialization is the memory heaviest part, the exception throws there - but it might be something else not being released properly.

Comment: @DekuDesu Any blogpost or reference might help :). Not sure exactly how to make the changes

Comment: @Compufreak Also possible as you mentioned, after getting the response from the network and getting the POCO class, I have some slight manipulations on the class before inserting into database ( dapper orm)

Comment: Please share a [mcve].

Comment: @mjwills Sure, will add that. Give me some time

Comment: Any update on this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got a feedback from one of the senior developer. He asked me to switch from `ReadAsStreamAsync` to `ReadAsByteArrayAsync`. Now I don't get the error anymore and its stable in production also

```
private async Task<T> CallApiAsync<T>(string url)
        {
            using var httpResponseMessage = await _httpClient.GetAsync(url);
            if (httpResponseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var responseBody = await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsByteArrayAsync(); //this fixed the issue
                return JsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>(responseBody);
            }
            var errors = await httpResponseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            throw GetDomainError(httpResponseMessage.StatusCode, url, errors);
        }
```